# Why am i getting "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." error?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am continuously getting " Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." error and I am totally stuck here. What am I doing wrong here please help me figure out and help me get out of this error.

This is my index.js file where I have integrated redux store to the app.

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose} from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootSaga from './sagas'
import { postsReducer } from './reducers/posts'
import Routes from './routes';

import './styles/style.css'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ postsReducer })
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)))
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router><Routes /></Router>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

this is my saga.js

```
import { take, put, call, fork, select, takeEvery, all, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import PostApi from './api/postApi';
import { gotPosts } from './actions/celebrity';
import { POSTS } from '../types'

export function* getAllPosts () {
    const posts = yield call(PostApi.getPosts, {})
    console.log('postssss', posts)
    yield put(gotPosts(posts.data))
}

export function* watchGetPosts () {
    yield takeLatest(POSTS, getAllPosts)
}


export default function* root() {
    yield all([  fork(watchGetPosts) ])
}
```

this is my action.js

```
import { POSTS } from '../../types';


export const gotPosts = (data) => {
    return {
        type: POSTS,
        data,
    }
}

export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(gotPosts);
}
```

this is component page where i dispatched action.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getPosts } from '../actions/celebrity';

const { Meta } = Card;

class  MainPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.props)
        this.props.getPosts();
    }
    render() {
        return <Row type="flex" className="main" justify="center" align="between">
             ......
        </Row>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        posts: state.postsReducer
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getPosts: () => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
    },
   });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

postsReducer

```
export const postsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type){
        case POSTS:
            return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dispatch **function** w/o middleware support.

Problem originates from mapDispatchToProps:

```
{
  getPosts: () => { dispatch(getPosts()); }   
}
```

tracing down to your actions.js, `getPosts()` returns `dispatch => dispatch(gotPosts)`, which is actually a function not an action(plan javascript object), redux dispatch by default doesn't recognize functions, unless you use middleware to enhance it, [redux thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for example.

Since you already have redux saga for async flow, simply dispatch an action from mapDispatchToProps should be fine, also consider create separate actions to differentiate `POSTS_REQUEST`, `POSTS_RECEIVE`, `POSTS_FAILURE` if possible.

```
import {POST} from '....../actionTypes'
...
{
  getPosts: () => { dispatch({ type: POST }); }   
}
```

Comment: thanks alot after I changed as per you say the error I was getting in console didn't appear but I am getting this error in "Given action "POSTS", reducer "postsReducer" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined in redux saga" if you could guide me what I am doing wrong here it would be great help for me.

Comment: add a defaultState for your `postReducer` using [default params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) like

`postReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action)`

Comment: above I have added my postsReducer

Comment: Did PostApi.getPosts() call succeed, was your logged action.data === 'undefined'?

Comment: It was some mistake in mine finally solved . You suggestion helped me thanks